# Perl/mod_perl: map use'd modules to paths with special characters

Tags: perl, mod-perl

Probably my question is a simple one, but I can't find an answer in docs and I hope someone could help.

**Q.:** Which are the rules of mapping filenames and filesystem paths to *use*'d /  *require*'d modules and the names used for *package* declarations, especially when there are used non-standard symbols like dots or commas?  It also would be nice to find out the similar answer for mod_perl's *PerlModule* and *PerlRequire* Apache directives related to these scenarios.

As a concrete examle, I have a mod_perl project located in a path with dots and commas like

```
/var/www/projects/my.awesome.project,with,comma/code
```

and I have to load in Apache's *conf* file the code of a module:

```
PerlModule my.awesome.project,with,comma::code::MyModule
```

I also have to declare my *package* like

```
package my.awesome.project,with,comma::code::MyModule;
```

(one of my custom paths from @INC points to /var/www/projects)

Of course this doesn't work. These paths must be mapped to something else. Or isn't it  possible at all and everyone have to use paths containg only alphanumeric symbols and underscores?

Thank you in advance for any help/answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl package names are [identifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Variable-names), which means they must start with a letter or underscore, and contain only letters, numbers, and underscore.  They can also be multiple identifiers separated by `::`.  The only filename mapping is that `::` gets converted to `/` (or whatever the system directory separator is).  Commas and periods are not allowed in package names.

[`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@INC) doesn't have that restriction, so you could add `/var/www/projects/my.awesome.project,with,comma` to it and then name the package `code::MyModule`.  But you're probably better off just sticking with alphanumerics and underscores for your directory names.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, cjm.<br> I was informed about "::" to  "/" mapping

Comment: I'm sorry for another message. I'm new here and "5 minutes for editing" was a surprize for me.   I was informed about "::" to  "/" mapping and I wasn't wachtful about package names which are identifiers. But my question is more from the mod_perl domain than from pure Perl. I meant maybe there is a _hidden_ mapping like the one used by Apache::Registry when a script filename are mapped to an internal package module with an appended `Apache::ROOT` prefix and mapping periods to "_2e".

Comment: @ArtM, no, mod_perl doesn't do anything like that for normal packages.  Apache::Registry does that because it's dealing with multiple scripts that all expected to be package `main` and getting them to co-exist.